# Running google-chrome in chroot

Tags: bash, google-chrome, chroot

I've installed schroot by following https://wiki.debian.org/Schroot
Than after going into my newly created chroot I've done

```sh
$ sudo schroot -c google-chrome
$ cd ~
$ apt-get update
$ apt-get install curl -y
$ curl -k -O https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
$ dpkg -i google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
$ apt-get -f install
$ exit
```

After all that when trying to run google-chrome

```sh
$ schroot -c google-chrome
$ google-chrome
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/fonts.conf", line 100: unknown element "blank"
[23232:23253:0924/174712.957580:ERROR:bus.cc(394)] Failed to connect to the bus: Failed to connect to socket /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket: No such file or directory
(google-chrome:23232): dconf-CRITICAL **: unable to create directory '/run/user/1000/dconf': Permission denied.  dconf will not work properly.
(google-chrome:23232): dconf-CRITICAL **: unable to create directory '/run/user/1000/dconf': Permission denied.  dconf will not work properly.
(google-chrome:23232): dconf-CRITICAL **: unable to create directory '/run/user/1000/dconf': Permission denied.  dconf will not work properly.
(google-chrome:23232): dconf-CRITICAL **: unable to create directory '/run/user/1000/dconf': Permission denied.  dconf will not work properly.
(google-chrome:23232): dconf-CRITICAL **: unable to create directory '/run/user/1000/dconf': Permission denied.  dconf will not work properly.
(google-chrome:23232): dconf-CRITICAL **: unable to create directory '/run/user/1000/dconf': Permission denied.  dconf will not work properly.
(google-chrome:23232): dconf-CRITICAL **: unable to create directory '/run/user/1000/dconf': Permission denied.  dconf will not work properly.
(google-chrome:23232): dconf-CRITICAL **: unable to create directory '/run/user/1000/dconf': Permission denied.  dconf will not work properly.
(google-chrome:23232): dconf-CRITICAL **: unable to create directory '/run/user/1000/dconf': Permission denied.  dconf will not work properly.
(google-chrome:23232): dconf-CRITICAL **: unable to create directory '/run/user/1000/dconf': Permission denied.  dconf will not work properly.
(google-chrome:23232): dconf-CRITICAL **: unable to create directory '/run/user/1000/dconf': Permission denied.  dconf will not work properly.
(google-chrome:23232): dconf-CRITICAL **: unable to create directory '/run/user/1000/dconf': Permission denied.  dconf will not work properly.
(google-chrome:23232): dconf-CRITICAL **: unable to create directory '/run/user/1000/dconf': Permission denied.  dconf will not work properly.
(google-chrome:23232): dconf-CRITICAL **: unable to create directory '/run/user/1000/dconf': Permission denied.  dconf will not work properly.
(google-chrome:23232): dconf-CRITICAL **: unable to create directory '/run/user/1000/dconf': Permission denied.  dconf will not work properly.
(google-chrome:23232): dconf-CRITICAL **: unable to create directory '/run/user/1000/dconf': Permission denied.  dconf will not work properly.
(google-chrome:23232): dconf-CRITICAL **: unable to create directory '/run/user/1000/dconf': Permission denied.  dconf will not work properly.
[23232:23250:0924/174712.963204:ERROR:platform_shared_memory_region_posix.cc(275)] Creating shared memory in /dev/shm/.com.google.Chrome.TK1LS0 failed: Permission denied (13)
[23232:23250:0924/174712.963234:ERROR:platform_shared_memory_region_posix.cc(278)] Unable to access(W_OK|X_OK) /dev/shm: Permission denied (13)
[23232:23250:0924/174712.963245:FATAL:platform_shared_memory_region_posix.cc(280)] This is frequently caused by incorrect permissions on /dev/shm.  Try 'sudo chmod 1777 /dev/shm' to fix.
Trace/breakpoint trap
```

Unfortunately after google for quite a while I was unable to find a sollution.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe in file: /etc/schroot/your-profile-name/fstab

you need to add:

```
/run/user/1000 /run/user/1000 none rw,bind,uid=1000,gid=1000 0 0
```

... or otherwise a single reference to all /run tree, ... while disabling all other /run/* mounts. but this is no good, it implies many mounts and unmounts.

```
/run           /run            none    rw,rbind         0       0
```